# Print a string x number of times in Python

Tags: python-3.x

1. Print out a message addressed to them that tells them the year that they will turn 100 years old.
2. Ask the user for another number and print out that many copies of the previous message.
3. Print out that many copies of the previous message on separate lines.

   ```
   Name = input("Enter your name: ")
   Age = int(input("Enter your age: "))

   print(f"{Name} will turn 100 in: ", CurrentYear + (100-Age))

   num = int(input("Enter any number: "))

   print(num * (f"{Name} will turn 100 in: CurrentYear + (100-Age)",))
   ```

I am not getting desired results for the 2,3.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print("\n".join([f"{Name} will turn 100 in: {CurrentYear + (100-Age)}" for x in range (0,num)]))
```

Output:

```py
Name = "Name"
CurrentYear = 2022
Age = 5
num = 5

# Name will turn 100 in: 2117
# Name will turn 100 in: 2117
# Name will turn 100 in: 2117
# Name will turn 100 in: 2117
# Name will turn 100 in: 2117
```

Is this what you are looking for?